# How to show code but hide output in RMarkdown?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I want my html file to show the code, but not the output of this chunk:

````
```{r echo=True, include=FALSE}
fun <- function(b)
    {
    for(a in b)
        {print(a)
        return(a * a)}
    }
y <- fun(b)
```
````

When I run the code, i need the print to see the progress (it is quite a long function in reality).

But in the knitr file, I use the output in a further chunk, so I do not want to see it in this one (and there's no notion of progress, since the code has already been run).

This `echo=True, include=FALSE` here does not work: the whole thing is hidden (which is the normal behavior of `include=FALSE`).

**What are the parameters I could use to hide the prints, but show my code?**

Comment: Try `{r echo=T, results='hide'}`

Comment: Nice, that's exactly what I was looking for! I hadn't seen that `results` parameter before

Comment: But how would one hide _any and all_ output? Using `results='hide'` will still show things like warnings, like when an object is masked when using `library(package)`. Is there an option to hide everything that would be printed to the console?

Comment: You can do that with `warn.conflicts=F, quietly=T` in your `library` command, like `library(package, warn.conflicts=F, quietly=T)`

Comment: I have no idea why but this does not work for me

Answer (score 113, accepted):

As @ J_F answered in the comments, using `{r echo = T, results = 'hide'}`.

I wanted to expand on their answer - there are great resources you can access to determine all possible options for your chunk and output display - I keep a printed copy at my desk!

You can find them either on the RStudio Website under [Cheatsheets](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/) (look for the R Markdown cheatsheet **and** R Markdown Reference Guide) or, in RStudio, navigate to the "Help" tab, choose "Cheatsheets", and look for the same documents there.

Finally to set **default chunk options**, you can run (in your first chunk) something like the following code if you want most chunks to have the same behavior:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = T,
                      results = "hide")
```
````

Later, you can **modify the behavior of individual chunks** like this, which will replace the default value for *just* the results option.

````
```{r analysis, results="markup"}
# code here
```
````

Comment: really nice. I find it very helpful when doing sudo codes or just creating a notebook with functioning code(that I can test) but excluding the output so that I can keep it short and tidy! Thanks.

Comment: @LachlanMacnish now I have a desk 3 days a week? lol

Answer (score 62):

The `results = 'hide'` option doesn't prevent other messages to be printed.
To hide them, the following options are useful:

- `{r, error=FALSE}`
- `{r, warning=FALSE}`
- `{r, message=FALSE}`

In every case, the corresponding warning, error or message will be printed to the console instead.

Answer (score 30):

````
```{r eval=FALSE}
````

The document will display the code by default but will prevent the code block from being executed, and thus will also not display any results.

Comment: For me, I wanted to show the code and not the plot so I used `echo=TRUE, eval=FALSE`

Comment: that's much better. For me `result="hide"` was only showing the last line of the code, `eval=F` showed the whole thing.

Comment: `eval=F` only is good if you don't have to use the result of this chunk into the next ones.

Comment: I agreed with @igorkf, `eval=F` is not suitable if that chunk is the chunk used for the next ones. Use `echo=T, results='hide'` instead.

Comment: @igorkf - Yes I also agree. eval=F will not run the code block. So any results won't be available for the remainder of the script. These options all have use cases.

Answer (score 5):

For muting `library("name_of_library")` codes, meanly just showing the codes, `{r loadlib, echo=T, results='hide', message=F, warning=F}` is great. And imho a better way than `library(package, warn.conflicts=F, quietly=T)`

Comment: `library(package, warn.conflicts=F, quietly=T)` suppresses messages in the console but not in the HTML output when Knitr knits to HTML.

Answer (score 5):

For completely silencing the output, here what works for me

````
```{r error=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
invisible({capture.output({


# Your code here
2 * 2
# etc etc


})})
```
````

The 5 measures used above are

1. `error = FALSE`
2. `warning = FALSE`
3. `message = FALSE`
4. `invisible()`
5. `capture.output()`

Answer (score 4):

To hide warnings, you can also do 
`{r, warning=FALSE}`