# How to hide import messages when importing a library?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am creating an R Markdown file for a report.

In a code chunk, I have written:

```
library("tidyverse")
```

I have tried the various options from this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47710427/how-to-show-code-but-hide-output-in-rmarkdown) but I cannot seem to hide the following lines:

```
## v ggplot2 3.3.2     v purrr   0.3.4
## v tibble  3.0.4     v dplyr   1.0.2
## v tidyr   1.1.2     v stringr 1.4.0
## v readr   1.4.0     v forcats 0.5.0
```

and separately:

```
## -- Conflicts ------------------------------------------ tidyverse_conflicts() --
## x dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
## x dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
```

I have tried:

- results='markup'
- message="FALSE"
- warning="FALSE"

I want to show the code, but not the information that it returns.

Comment: What did you write in the code chunck?

Comment: Added the code chunk @Waldi

Comment: I would suggest  `echo=T, warning=FALSE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make all my code chunks as follows to suppress warnings and messages:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE,message=FALSE}
````

Comment: the code will not show if I do echo=false. I would like to show the code but not the output.

Comment: In that case, use echo=TRUE    Remember TRUE/FALSE are all CAPS.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I'm not sure what I did wrong before!

Comment: @Alex You probably used quotes around `FALSE`. At least that’s what you wrote in the question.